# regex that matches everything except a constant

Tags: regex

I need a regexp that will match everything except a single constant (case ignored)

Example for constant **ALL**, should match words like: dog, MOUSE, mall, alligator. But it shouldn't match: all, ALL, alL.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: No, that's *not* a duplicate. "Not containing" a word is not the same as "not being" a word.

Comment: @Tim You are right. You would have to add placeholders for start/end of string AND case insensitivity to make it a duplicate. (Retracting my close vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?si)^(?!all$).*
```

will match any string except `all` (case-insensitively).

`(?i)` makes the regex case-insensitive, `(?s)` allows the dot to match any character, including newlines. If you don't expect newlines in your input, you can remove the `s`.

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/kU8hW9).