# Is there a way to match everything except a constant string using Go.Regexp?

Tags: regex, go

I have found many similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251490/regex-that-matches-everything-except-a-constant) that do not work with the [Go regex syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

The string that I am attempting to match against is in the form of `anything/anything/somestring`. With the pattern `\/.*\/.*\/(.*)`, I will match `somestring`, but I am trying to match anything except strings that contain `somestring`.

Most answers propose using something like `\/.*\/.*\/((?!somestring).*)`, however in golang regexp I get: `? The preceding token is not quantifiable`.

For clarification: `/test/test/MATCH` would produce a match while `/test/test/somestring` would not. Is this possible with the (limited) Go regex syntax?

Comment: It looks like almost everything is _NOT SUPPORTED_. Is it really a regex engine? Anyway, assertions are not available ( it says ) so `(?!somestring)`, which is what you need, is out. The only way around it is to use your regex `\/.*\/.*\/(.*)` in a while loop. Each match, string compare group 1 with `somestring`.

Comment: RE2 (which Go implements) doesn't support lookarounds. Just check the submatches yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

Go `regexp` module does not support lookaheads because this package guarantees to run in O(n) time, and the authors did not find a way to introduce lookarounds without violating these constraints.

**However**, you may use different workarounds. For the current one, you can use the http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/misc/non-match-regex Web service that generates POSIX-compatible negated patterns. E.g. for `somestring`, it generates a `^([^s]|s(s|o(s|m(s|es(omes)*(s|t(s|r(s|i(s|ns)))|o(s|ms)))))*([^os]|o([^ms]|m([^es]|e([^s]|s(omes)*([^ost]|t([^rs]|r([^is]|i([^ns]|n[^gs])))|o([^ms]|m([^es]|e[^s]))))))))*(s(s|o(s|m(s|es(omes)*(s|t(s|r(s|i(s|ns)))|o(s|ms)))))*(o((me?)?|mes(omes)*(t(r?|rin?)|o(me?)?)?))?)?$` regex, and in order to use it in your original regex, all you need is to replace the last `(.*)` with `(<part after ^>)`, i.e. the regex will look like

```golang
/[^/]*/[^/]*/(([^s]|s(s|o(s|m(s|es(omes)*(s|t(s|r(s|i(s|ns)))|o(s|ms)))))*([^os]|o([^ms]|m([^es]|e([^s]|s(omes)*([^ost]|t([^rs]|r([^is]|i([^ns]|n[^gs])))|o([^ms]|m([^es]|e[^s]))))))))*(s(s|o(s|m(s|es(omes)*(s|t(s|r(s|i(s|ns)))|o(s|ms)))))*(o((me?)?|mes(omes)*(t(r?|rin?)|o(me?)?)?))?)?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JLkVQc/1/).

To make sure the regex only captures the part after third backslash, the first two `.*` patterns are replaced with `[^/]*` that match zero or more chars other than `/`. (In the demo, I added `\n`, too, to avoid matching across lines in the single multiline string demo).

**Originally accepted answer**

The `anything/anything/somestring` should not be expressed as `\/.*\/.*\/(.*)`. The first `.*` matches up to the last but one `/` in the string. You need to use a negated character class `[^/]` (not the `/` should not be escaped in Go regex).

Since RE2 that Go uses does not support lookaheads, you need to capture (as [JimB mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515407/is-there-a-way-to-match-everything-except-a-constant-string-using-go-regexp#comment72168422_42515407)) *all three parts* you are interested in, and after checking the capture group #1 value, decide what to return:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := "anything/anything/somestring"
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`^[^/]+/[^/]+/(.*)`)
    val := r.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    // fmt.Println(val[1]) // -> somestring
    if len(val) > 1 && val[1] != "somestring" { // val has more than 1 element and is not equal to somestring?
        fmt.Println(val[1])      // Use val[1]
    } else {
        fmt.Println("No match")  // Else, report no match
    }
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/3vlJ5zq6l7)

Answer (score 8):

Golang intentionally leaves this feature out as there is no way to implement it in O(n) time to satisfy the constraints of a true Regular Expression [according to Russ Cox](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/7qgSDWPIh_E):

> The lack of generalized assertions, like the lack of backreferences, 
>   is not a statement on our part about regular expression style.  It is 
>   a consequence of not knowing how to implement them efficiently.  If 
>   you can implement them while preserving the guarantees made by the 
>   current package regexp, namely that it makes a single scan over the 
>   input and runs in O(n) time, then I would be happy to review and 
>   approve that CL.  However, I have pondered how to do this for five 
>   years, off and on, and gotten nowhere.

It looks like the best way to do this is to manually check the match after as JimB mentions above.

Answer (score 1):

There is [regexp2](https://github.com/dlclark/regexp2) which implement a feature-rich RegExp engine for Go,  it doesn't have constant time guarantees like the built-in `regexp` package, but it allows backtracking. You can use then something like `(?!somestring)` to solve your problem.