# regex in RE2 syntax with Negate match

Tags: regex, re2

How can I write a regex in **RE2 syntax** to match strings which contain 'register' but doesn't contain 'dashboard'?

E.g.

- https://domain.co/auth/login - **NOT**
- https://domain.co/auth/register?emailgfdg%40g.com&token=5F6DCCA1 - **OK**
- https://domain.co/auth/register?emailgfdg%40g.com&dashboardtoken=5F6DCCA1 - **NOT**

PS 'dashboard' (if any) is always placed after 'register'

I'd use `.*register(?!.*dashboard).*` but RE2 doesn't support that syntax.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/r5OteF/1

Comment: Great! I havn't uderstand but it works perfect!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515407/is-there-a-way-to-match-everything-except-a-constant-string-using-go-regexp to understand what I did.