# Ginkgo - skip tests that don't match an expression

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds, ginkgo

Trying to write a REGEX for the ginkgo `--skip` flag, that would skip tests that do NOT contain a string ("test1").
AFAIK golang doesn't support '!' ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515407/is-there-a-way-to-match-everything-except-a-constant-string-using-go-regexp))

I know I can use `--focus`, but prefer `--skip` for reasons.

How do I go about creating a negative match expression for this purpose?

I tried using `(?i)^(?!.*test1).*` but this expression doesn't work, as the "!" is treated literally and is not supported in golang.

Comment: did you already tried the ginkgo filtering by label https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#spec-labels ?

Comment: Unfortunately our tests are not labeled well